# Work Around for Firefox Table Border Rendering Bug

Tags: css, firefox

I am using a table to render a calendar.  I have noticed an odd rendering bug in table cell border rendering in Firefox version 3.6 through 7.  Here's a screen capture:

[image: table border rendering bug]

As you can see, the border gets "bent" when I scroll.  Also, there are gaps between the horizontal and vertical border where it isn't "bent".  A live example can be seen on [this web site](http://www.irscfoundation.org/p/24/calendar).

I don't see this behavior in Chrome, Safari, or Internet Explorer.

---

**UPDATE**

I am still seeing this issue in Firefox 20. I have noticed that single pixel borders do not exhibit this behavior, only two pixels or more.

Comment: only happened the first time i opened the page, refreshing makes the bug disappear, ctrl+click on table cells reproduces it

Comment: @max4ever - That's true for me and the "bent" issue, but the one pixel gap issue remains.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a problem whith border-collapse:

Here is a solution for your problem: http://www.charlesgarwood.com/blog/?p=13

What to do:

- change `border-collapse` from `collapse` to `separate`
- change the `border-width` of the `<td>`s and `<th>`s from `2px` to `1px`
- give the `<table>` itself a `1px` `border`

Give some conditional comments like described in the link

Comment: Thanks! This looks like one of those situations where the cure is almost uglier than the symptom.